why is my code not changing to the next page which is the suggestion page after hitting the button it says unknown error during login
why is my code not changing to the next page which is the suggestion page after hitting the button it says unknown error during login.
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import logIn from '@salesforce/apex/LoginController.logIn';

export default class LoginComponent extends LightningElement {
    email = '';
    singleLoginId = '';
    @track errorMessage = '';

    handleEmailChange(event) {
        this.email = event.target.value;
    }

    handleLoginIdChange(event) {
        this.singleLoginId = event.target.value;
    }

    handleLogin() {
        console.log('Login button clicked');
        logIn({ email: this.email, singleLoginId: this.singleLoginId })
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Login result:', result);
                if (result.success) {
                    // Store student details in session storage
                    sessionStorage.setItem('student', JSON.stringify(result.student));
                    console.log('Student stored in session storage:', result.student);
                    // Redirect to the suggestion page
                    window.location.href = '/c/suggestionComponent.app';
                } else {
                    this.errorMessage = result.message;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error during login:', error);
                this.errorMessage = error.body && error.body.message ? 
                    'Error during login: ' + error.body.message : 'Unknown error during login';
            });
    }
}

im expecting it to redirect to a suggestion page after filling the login credentials

"Unknown error during login" sounds like there is a problem with your server-side code.
